# Литература Python под веб

Tags: python, книги, php

Собс-но, посоветуйте сабж. Приоритетнее была бы такая литература, которая позволила бы легко перейти с РНР.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала, наверное, нужно освоить основы Питона (Питон - язык многосторонний), а потом уже переходить к специальным разделам.

Comment: Меня остальные разделы не интересуют, именно веб. Под другие задачи мне по нраву другие языки (:

Comment: Это понятно. Но сначала нужно освоить основы языка: грамматику, синтаксис, ООП. Классическая книга Марка Лутца. Она ооочень большая, но все читать не обязательно.

Comment: Читал книгу лутца в захлеб. Если на самом деле хотеть изучить питон - нужно прочитать от корки до корки.

Answer (score 2):

1 - марк лутц
2 - А.Сузи
3-100 - google.ru
в любом случае вам необходимо прочитать хотя бы несколько страниц любой из существующих книг по Python т.к python изначально является не языком web разработки, а языком для прикладного программирования (в большей его части)..
после освоения самых азов учитывая что у вас уже есть опыт программирования на php берете любой мануал web фреймворка (вероятнее всего ваш выбор пал на Django (например [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/))), а это уже далеко не тоже самое что стандартная библиотека модулей python.
удачи

Answer (score 1):

По моему опыту освоения питона, вполне хватит основ языка из практически любого учебника. В качестве фреймворка под веб посоветовал бы начать с tornado (http://www.tornadoweb.org/) или webpy (http://webpy.org/). Django для начинающего по моему, не лучший выбор. 
В любом случае, лучшие учебники это практические задачи и гугл.

Comment: Про практические задачи в последнем предложении согласен, при гугл - абсолютно не приемлю. Языки надо учить систематически, а не по отрывкам и статейкам.

Comment: Пример систематического изучения - школа или ВУЗ. Лекции - практические задания - лекции - практические задания. Отличие только в том, что задания можно выбирать интересные или полезные для себя. К сожалению, хороших учебников python+web не много. Учебник по Django я видел только один - конечно лучше чем ничего, но это далеко не все, что умеет питон. Так что - только практика)

Comment: По поводу книжек по Django: http://www.google.com/search?q=django&x=0&y=0&sitesearch=wowebook.pro

Answer (score 0):

Сначала изучи сам Python, есть еще более подробная книга по языку - Саммерфилд - Программирование на Python 3, а веб лучше изучать здесь - http://djbook.ru/.

Answer (score 0):

Немного не литература:), но, возможно, кое-где облегчит ваш переход с РНР:
http://www.php2python.com/
Ресурс, который помогает найти аналог РНР-шной функции для Питона.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону Web2py
web2py.com